# Order totals not displayed (i.e. blank) in Magento admin

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order

The order totals section of the Order View page is blank in Magento admin panel. All other information from the transaction is displayed on the order view (customers address etc and payment method) but the 'Order Totals' section is now blank.

Can anyone advise on how to troubleshoot this issue?

The following html is present but there's no content within it:

```
 <div class="box-right entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head"><h4>Order Totals</h4></div>
    <div class="order-totals"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some third party module is overriding this block. Try following things if this helps -

1) Try disabling all third party module one by one to check which one is creating problem.

2) You can enable path hint in magento admin to check path of actual phtml or block file overriding this core block. here is a reference link with guide on how to enable path hint in admin -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373481/enable-template-path-hint-in-admin-pages-magento

Comment: Dhanpat - we do not have access to SQL is there a way in 1.7 to turn on path hints in admin without needing to go in SQL? Or is there another way to debug - for example would this show in any logs?